# QML Animation with both "velocity" and infinite "loops"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to put together an animation in which I get to specify the velocity (rather than the duration) and which loops forever. I came up with two non-working examples:

**FirstTry.qml**

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
  width: 100; height: 100
  Text {
    text: "hello"
    NumberAnimation on x {
      to: 50;
      loops: Animation.Infinite;
      duration: 50 * Math.abs(to - from)
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following runtime warning while `hello` goes nuts on the screen (fair enough).

```
QDeclarativeExpression: Expression "(function() { return 50 * Math.abs(to - from) })" depends on non-NOTIFYable properties: 
    QDeclarativeNumberAnimation::to
    QDeclarativeNumberAnimation::from
```

**SecondTry.qml**

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
  width: 100; height: 100
  Text {
    text: "hello"
    SmoothedAnimation on x {
      to: 50;
      loops: Animation.Infinite;
      velocity: 50
    }
  }
}
```

This is more of a mistery -- `SmoothedAnimation` simply refuses to loop! The Animation runs once and then that's it.

So I have the following questions:

Is there a legal way to specify the velocity in the first example? I understand `SmoothedAnimation` is derived from `NumberAnimation`, so maybe it's possible in QML, not just in C++.

Is there a way to make `SmoothedAnimation` loop? Is the second example not working a bug or am I missing something?

Is there any other way to achieve these two behaviours at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

just add "from" parameter explicitly:

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
  width: 100; height: 100
  Text {
    text: "hello"
    NumberAnimation on x {
      from: 0;
      to: 50;
      loops: Animation.Infinite;
      duration: 50 * Math.abs(to - from)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did as a temporary solution, I'm not sure if it's adequate, but it seem to be doing just what I needed.

```
SmoothedAnimation on x {
  to: 50;
  //loops: Animation.Infinite;
  velocity: 50
  onComplete: { restart (); }
}
```

I'm still interested in the answers to the questions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Even if *SmoothedAnimation* doesn't accept *loops* parameter, you can place it inside *SequentialAnimation* and apply *loops* to this external cover. As an effect your smoothed animation will be played continuosly.